# Coding an X-Bitmap Loader in SDL?

Tags: c++, image, sdl, loading

Here's my code:

```
template<typename G, typename N> void load_xbm(G* g,N w, N h,unsigned char* data)
{
    Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

        /* SDL interprets each pixel as a 32-bit number, so our masks must depend
           on the endianness (byte order) of the machine */
    #if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
        rmask = 0xff000000;
        gmask = 0x00ff0000;
        bmask = 0x0000ff00;
        amask = 0x000000ff;
    #else
        rmask = 0x000000ff;
        gmask = 0x0000ff00;
        bmask = 0x00ff0000;
        amask = 0xff000000;
    #endif

    SDL_Surface* s = g->backend_surface();
    s = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE,w,h,16,rmask,gmask,bmask,amask);
    g->backend_surface( s );

    for (N x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        for(N y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            g->put_pixel(x,y,data[y*x]);
        }
    }

    SDL_Flip( s );
}
```

`g->backend_surface()` just returns an `SDL_Surface*` member in `G`. 
`w` is the width of the xbm bitmap, `h` is the height, `data` is an array of `unsigned char`s containing the colors of every pixel.

`g->put_pixel()` is a simple wrap over of the `putpixel` method in [SDL docs](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideo.html), which uses it's `backend_surface` as the first parameter to the example `putpixel` function.

Now when I execute it the program exits with `0x3`. By debugging the code I've found that it exits on the call to the `putpixel` method, note that the `putpixel` method is working fine elsewhere. I've also found out that it only exits when the `x` and `y` arguments to `putpixel` are *bigger than the original width and height of the Surface*, but haven't I resized the surface using `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` to the required width and height?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `SDL_FreeSurface` call in there? The former surface will leak.

Comment: @Xeo It's in the destructor of `G`.

Comment: No, I meant before calling `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`. You assign the old pointer, and a reference to the former surface is lost, resulting in the surface never being freed (they're reference counted).

Comment: oh I see. sorry, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing in the wild here...

This [SDL tutorial example](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideo.html) (point 2.5) says that the Surface must be locked before calling this function. Is yours?